# Mina deployment : invoke task once `current` symlink is updated

Tags: ruby, deployment, web-deployment, mina

I'm using [Mina](https://github.com/nadarei/mina) *(a simpler alternative to Capistrano)* to deploy my ruby websites, and I am trying to run some tasks once the `current` symlink has been updated.

So far, here's what I have in my deploy.rb file:

```
desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'

    to :launch do
      invoke :restart
    end
  end
end

desc "Manually restart Thin web server"
task :restart do
  in_directory "#{deploy_to}/current" do
    queue! %[bundle exec thin restart -C "#{thin_yml}"]
  end
end
```

My problem is that when Mina hits the `to :launch` block, the `current` symlink has not yet been updated, so either it does not exist (if it is the 1st deployment for this project) or it's still pointing to the n-1 release (and thus, the server uses an outdated version of the project).

So I'd like to be able to invoke my `:restart` task once the new release has been moved to the release directory and the current `symlink` has been updated.

Comment: is it possible to call `queue :'restart'` instead of invoking it directly?

Comment: Actually no, the ``queue`` command allows to run bash commands only. You meant to queue the ``:restart`` task instead of running it instantly if I'm correct. Actually, there seems to be something that is run after the ``to :launch do`` block according to tests I've made with ``mina deploy --verbose``, and that's what I'd need here, I think.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Found any solution?

Comment: I'm not alone anymore, yaaay ! Unfortunately, found no solution so far (I must admit I stopped looking into it). Currently, I manually use my ``mina restart`` task after a deploy. That's not perfect, but better than nothing, I guess.

Comment: Having the same issue since when I started using Mina. I'll add a bounty, want a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug of Mina. `in_directory` seems to not work properly when used inside a `to` context. A quick and dirty workaround would be adding `@commands[:default] = commands(@to)` at the end of the `in_directory` block.

```
desc "Manually restart Thin web server"
task :restart do
  in_directory "#{deploy_to}/current" do
    queue! %[bundle exec thin restart -C "#{thin_yml}"]
    @commands[:default] = commands(@to)
  end
end
```